# Lookup table with EF Codefirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to create Resource and RelatedResources table with EF Code First as below:

```
Table Resource
int Id
string ResourceName
int Category

Table RelatedResource
int ResourceId
int RelatedResourceId
```

I tried as below but 
 Error: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ResourceId' on type 'Models.ResourceRelated' is not valid. The navigation property 'Resource' was not found on the dependent type 'Models.ResourceRelated'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

```
public class ResourceRelated
    {
        [ForeignKey("Resource")]
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public virtual Resource Resoure { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Resource> RelatedResource { get; set; }
    }
```

Kindly Advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want RelatedResource table, than you want many-to-many relationship. You can achieve this in next way

```
public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Resoure")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedResource> RelatedResource { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ResourceRelated")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedResource> ResourceRelated { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedResource
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Resoure")]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("ResourceRelated")]
    public int ResourceRelatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Resource Resoure { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource ResourceRelated { get; set; }
}
```

If you prefer do not work with RelatedResource in code, than you can do next

```
public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> RelatedResource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> ResourceRelated { get; set; }
}
```

After you need next additional configuration

```
internal class ResourceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Resource>
{
    public ResourceConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(s => s.ResourceRelated).WithMany(c => c.RelatedResource)
            .Map(cs => { 
                cs.MapLeftKey("ResourceId"); 
                cs.MapRightKey("RelatedResourceId");
                cs.ToTable("RelatedResource"); }
            );
    }
}
```

And finally add this configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ///other configuration code
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ResourceConfiguration());
}
```

But if you want to have "resource tree" than you do not need RelatedResource table

```
public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int? ResourceRelatedId { get; set; }

    public Resource ResourceRelated { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ResourceRelatedId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> RelatedResource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would like to get: Select * from dbo.ResourceDetails
Where ResourceId in 
(Select rr.RelatedResourceId from dbo.ResourceDetails rd 
Inner Join dbo.RelatedResource rr On rd.ResourceId = rr.ResourceId
rd.id = 1